# Delete the word null from text string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that is like this `word1 - null - word3`, is it possible to write an sql query to remove the word `null` from the string of text?

Thanks

Comment: REPLACE(column, 'oldval','newval')

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`REPLACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @Test AS VARCHAR(32)
SELECT @Test = 'word1 - null - word3'

SELECT REPLACE(@Test, 'null - ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE`.

**Query**

```
declare @str as varchar(50);
set @str = 'word1 - null - word3';

select replace(@str,'null','');
```